# How to use the key special attribute inside the v-for directive using an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

1. List item

A have  variable that contains an array of arrays of objects like this :

```
let FooVar: Array<Array<FooObject>> = [] ;
```

i want to loop through it inside a component something like this

```
<span v-for="item in FooVar" :key="XXX">
```

what should i put inside the key attribute ?

Comment: For example, If your item has an `id` then you can put this inside the key property

Comment: @RenaudC5 that for a simple array of objects , in my case i have an array of arrays of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#key)

> The key special attribute is primarily used as a hint for Vue's virtual DOM algorithm to identify vnodes when diffing the new list of nodes against the old list.

It will also be used for

- Properly trigger lifecycle hooks of a component
- Trigger transitions

The only requirements is that your keys must not have any duplicates

> Children of the same common parent must have unique keys. Duplicate keys will cause render errors.

---

In general the best way is by adding an unique identifier to the item with for example an id comming from the database

```js
<span v-for="item in FooVar" :key="item.id">
```

If you don't have any id, then you can use the index of the item in the list.

*Note* that this is **NOT** optimzed and [see here why](https://rimdev.io/the-v-for-key/)

```js
<span v-for="(item, index) in FooVar" :key="index">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put index:

```
<span v-for="(item, index) in FooVar" :key="index">
```